# The Word "Beautiful" in Titles

Tags: discussion, specific-user, titles

I've noticed that there are two users ([here](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/178781/dorian-gray?tab=questions) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/178776/jackie-poehler?tab=questions)) are including the word "Beautiful" in the title of almost every question they ask. It seems to me that the purpose of including that word in the title is largely to attract more attention to the question (or for perhaps some other motive) and doesn't actually help increase the visibility of the question to other people who might have the same question, nor provide any extra insight into what the problem might actually be.

By my own stylistic standards, I would certainly remove the word from the title, but I feel that doing so would clearly conflict with the author's intention. If this is simply a behavior that I, personally, find annoying, I'd rather defer to the author and keep the titles, but if it is a genuine issue, it would be good to do something about it - and I don't know which of those options it is.

Is this behavior problematic? Should something be done about it?

Comment: It’s harmless, and I find it mildly amusing. (Though I may end up with a hardwired connection between *beautiful* and the name *Jackie*!) It may even serve a small useful purpose: those titles aren’t likely to conflict with others.

Comment: [Other users](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1035361/revisions) are picking it up, too: existing titles serve as examples to others. What will they do when "beautiful" becomes too commonplace and stops grabbing attention? After a few iterations, we'll have "An AWESOME inequality that will Rock Your Socks Off!!!".

Comment: Older related posts: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5082/should-we-retitle-posts-whose-titles-contain-interesting and http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2664/how-should-we-treat-subjective-titles

Comment: On the same (amusing) vein, [Ugly in titles](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=title%3Augly+is%3Aquestion) almost reads like a mathematical term. Beautiful beats ugly by 38 to 12. I also see 3 horribles and 62 elegants.

Comment: @J.W.Perry I'm shocked nobody used "charming" yet.

Comment: Interesting: 387 [interesting](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=title%3Ainteresting+is%3Aquestion) questions, and 376 [easy](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=title%3Aeasy+is%3Aquestion) questions.

Comment: And just two [wicked](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=title%3Awicked) ones.

Comment: Kind of hypocritical to use it yourself, don't you think?  I'm only joking!

Comment: Hmmm... maybe I should go with [supercalifragilisticexpialidocious](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCMQyCkwAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DtRFHXMQP-QU&ei=ELdyVOewDomvyQT-qoFg&usg=AFQjCNHigOo-WQh4pCslEgBsVQL6HeASWg&sig2=v5F-l4G2XBT3-ZTPq6twGg&bvm=bv.80185997,d.aWw) for maximum attention...

Comment: This question should be renamed as *A beautiful question on "beautiful" title(s)*. :)

Comment: You can always downvote the questions if you consider them less beutiful than their author claims.

Comment: We should introduce a new close reason: "**question claims beauty...** This question is claiming to be beautiful. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what is beautiful about it. Please add a short explanation about its relative merits."

Comment: @user1729, haha love it.

Comment: @Rafflesiaarnoldii both of the wicked ones are concerning "wicked" integrals!

Comment: @J.W.Perry I've seen the term *ugly* used as a mathematical term. Herrlich, Axiom of Choice, [p.119](http://books.google.com/books?id=JXIiGGmq4ZAC&pg=PA119), Definition 5.3. Non-continuous solutions of the Cauchy-equation are called *ugly*.

Comment: and 62 [elegant](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=title%3Aelegant), although those have more objective standing

Comment: @Raff And, shortly thereafter, "First, I divided by $x+2$.  What happens next will shock you!"  Woe is the day when we have linkbait titles on SE. `:)`

Comment: I would not call the behaviour problematic. The user's id should give a subtle hint as to why the word beautiful appears so often. A little Wilde maybe?

Comment: @copper.hat I'm going to start adding "Macarena" to the titles, because I like the song so much.

Comment: @Raff: I'm not sure how to work "It's all about the bass" into my questions...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's useless, and should be replaced with a more descriptive title. [Like this](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/991885/revisions).

The *Related* column of every question heavily relies on the titles, and it does a decent job of picking up LaTeX syntax (unlike the regular search function). If a formula (e.g., an inequality) is used in the title, it increases the chance of truly related questions showing up, as opposed to other questions with "little" or "beautiful" in titles.

Comment: It serves a useful purpose if you feel like downvoting some questions for being poorly manipulative.

Comment: Not sure if you are joking, but even *I* don't downvote questions based on title alone. I'd rather fix the title.

Comment: I am serious but not facetious (as you are Mr Downvote you might have taken it personally which it wasn't). I'm on the record for disliking certain ways of presentation (terrible grammar, ...) as disrespectful; and drawing attention by false advertising is new, but not ok either. I downvoted some of theirs (I'm not a fan of cleaning up for users though as they should speak in their voice, on which you can comment by voting).

Comment: ....probably the only humor is that I have a grammar error in a comment proselytizing about grammar...:)

Comment: @gnometorule: Viewing poor grammar as disrespectful makes little sense on a site with so many people for whom English is a second (or later) language.

Comment: The user's [comment](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/991885/show-that-frac1a-frac1b-frac1c-geq-frac9abc-for-positiv#comment2031708_991885) "idk, just that more people see them" does suggest that using  *beautiful* in titles is intentional clickbait. (Never mind the question being a duplicate, which I now voted to close as such.)

Comment: @Brian: This is getting off-topic, but I obviously agree (I'm no native speaker myself but after 20 years in the US it's hardly fair to judge, say, undergrads in non-English speaking countries). It's not really grammar, and I've written what I mean elsewhere here (probably not as well as I should have). It's the "whats ur opinin guys on dat" type. While you are too chill and gentle to mind, you are an emeritus and among asker's audience. I don't like that, and find it disrespectful.

Comment: @gnometorule: Ah, I see. Yes, that is a bit different from the sort of problem that I had in mind! I don’t mind it personally, but I do wonder whether the asker realizes that it puts him or her at a disadvantage. (I’m actually made much more uncomfortable by the *sir* that I get, e.g., from many Indian students).

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I find the "sir" I get mildly amusing. Especially when my students start calling me "sir user1729".

Comment: The use of the work 'beautiful' in the title is a nod to one of the world's famous aesthetes.